# I have a C++ 2d array i have to call functions . it only averages every 5 locations ex [0][0] + [5][0] does thi look right or is there a better way

Tags: c++, arrays, function, average

I have a C++ 2d array i have to call functions . it only averages every 5 locations ex [0][0] + [5][0] does this look right or is there a better way
    //
    //  main.cpp
    //  homework 8
    //
    //  Created by Patrick Stark on 11/17/15.
    //  Copyright © 2015 Patrick Stark. All rights reserved.
    //

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int ROW_SIZE = 10;

const int COLUMN_SIZE = 1;

double avgAtt(const int a[][COLUMN_SIZE], int rowSize)
{
double attTotal = 0;
double attAvg = 0;

attTotal = a[0][0] + a[5][0];

attAvg = attTotal / 2;

return  attAvg;

}

double avgHomework(const int a[][COLUMN_SIZE], int rowSize)
{
double homeworkTotal = 0;

double homeworkAverage = 0;

homeworkTotal = a[1][0] + a[6][0];

homeworkAverage = homeworkTotal / 2;

return homeworkAverage;

}

int main ()
{
int aryData[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE] =
{{10},
{20},
{10},
{10},
{20},
{5},
{15},
{8},
{8},
{18}};

cout << avgAtt(aryData, 10)<<endl;

cout << avgHomework(aryData, 10)<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

**I dont have to average all the cells just every 5th one. Here is the assignment**

This chapter's program asks you to utilize a multi-dimensional array.

Read in from input, where every 6th row represents a new student's grades.

Row 1 is attendance, which is out of 10 points, Row 2 is homework, which is out of 30 points.
Row 3 is quizzes, which is out of 20 points, Row 4 is midterm which is out of 15 points.
Row 5 is Final, which is out of 25 points.

So, the first position in the array, aryData[0][0] will hold the value out of 10 points, 
aryData[0][1] will be the value out of 30 points, etc..

First, read in all of the data into a multidimensional array. Then, call a function that you send the array to and calculate the average of each grade type, such as attendance average is 8, homework average is 27, etc... and output it to the screen.

Next, call a function that you send the array to and calculate the average grade for the entire class. 
Output what the average is for the entire class. 
So as an example...

10
20
10
10
20
5
15
8
8
18

70 + 54

Attendance Avg: 7.5
Homework Avg: 17.5
Quizzes Avg: 9
Midterm Avg: 9
Final Avg: 19

Student Average: 62

At least 5 comments
It should compile
It should give the correct output as defined

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to ask this kind of question properly.

Comment: In general, average requires a sum divided by a quantity.  The sum is usually calculated using a `for` loop.  Your function doesn't loop.  You will need to sum up each element in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate the sum, by adding elements of the matrix (array).

For example, summing a column:

```
unsigned int sum = 0;
for (unsigned int row = 0; row < MAXIMUM_ROWS; ++row)
{
  sum = sum + matrix[row][column];
}
```

The standard C++ language does not have vector or matrix math functions; you'll have to use a library or write your own.

**Edit 1:  The Average**
The average is calculated by dividing the sum (as calculated above) by the quantity:

```
  double average = (double) sum / (double) MAXIMUM_ROWS;
```